# How do I add a WebView2 control to a CDialog resource in a MFC project?

Tags: mfc, webview2, cdialog

I have been able to download and build the sample projects from Microsoft. I can run the Win32 project and it displays a WebView2 object in the View and appears functional.

For my situation I want to use a `CDialog` as the parent for the WebView2 control and I can't work out how to do this. When I follow the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/win32) it is based on a View style object. In the instructions it says:

> ### Step 3 - Create a single WebView within the parent window
>
> Add a WebView to the main window.

I get lost here and don't knwo how to add the control to my basic `CDialog` project.

Thank you for your direction on how to deal with this.

Comment: The WebView2 control is created in code. I don't know whether there is a "Control" in the resource editor's Toolbox, though I doubt there is (if that is what you're asking). The code in the instructions is likely the most compact way of doing this. Compact is usually not the same as educational. The times when the MSDN samples were plain to follow C code are probably gone.

Comment: @IInspectable I see. This is where I am struggling. I want to be able to take the extents of a rectangle, from say a static frame on the dialog (invisible) and use its position to create this web view. And I can’t work it out.

Comment: I am going to look at this: https://mariusbancila.ro/blog/2020/01/29/using-microsoft-edge-in-a-native-windows-desktop-app-part-2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This alternative [tutorial](https://mariusbancila.ro/blog/2020/01/29/using-microsoft-edge-in-a-native-windows-desktop-app-part-2/) helped me. I downloaded the sample project, compiled it and it worked. Again, it was based on a application derived from a `CView`. However, I have managed to work out the principles required.

No doubt more will be involved as I continue to tweak the test application I am making.

1. Create a dialog based application using boiler place code.
2. Set the C++ Language Standard to ISO C++ 17.
3. Install two NuGet packages:

- [`Microsoft.Web.WebView2`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.WebView2) NuGet package
- [`Microsoft.Windows.ImplementationLibrary`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.ImplementationLibrary/) NuGet package

4. Change `InitInstance` to use `CoInitialize`.
5. Add the `ExitInstance` handler and call `UnCoinitialize`.

For testing purposes I simply used the dimensions of my dialog. Begin by adding a variable to your dialog class:

```
std::unique_ptr<CWebBrowser> m_pWebBrowser;
```

Then, in `OnInitDialog` you can do something like this:

```
m_pWebBrowser = std::make_unique<CWebBrowser>();

if (m_pWebBrowser != nullptr)
{
    CRect rectClient;
    GetClientRect(rectClient);

    m_pWebBrowser->CreateAsync(
        WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
        rectClient,
        this,
        1,
        [this]() {
            m_pWebBrowser->SetParent(this);
            m_pWebBrowser->DisablePopups();
            m_pWebBrowser->Navigate(L"https://jw.org", nullptr);

            m_pWebBrowser->RegisterCallback(CWebBrowser::CallbackType::TitleChanged, [this]() {
                CString title = m_pWebBrowser->GetTitle();

                AfxGetMainWnd()->SetWindowText(title);
                });
        });
}
```

For the test, I also added the `OnSize` handler:

```
void CMFCTestWebView2Dlg::OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy)
{
    CDialogEx::OnSize(nType, cx, cy);

    CRect rectClient;

    if (m_pWebBrowser != nullptr)
    {
        m_staticBrowser.GetClientRect(rectClient);
        m_staticBrowser.ClientToScreen(rectClient);
        ScreenToClient(rectClient);

        m_pWebBrowser->Resize(rectClient.Width(), rectClient.Height());
    }

}
```

The heart of this is the `CWebBrowser` class. This is available in the linked tutorial and all I did was adjust the `SetParentView` method so that it accepted a `CWnd` pointer instead.

Oh, and you add `DestroyWindow` to the dialog class:

```
BOOL CMFCTestWebView2Dlg::DestroyWindow()
{
    m_pWebBrowser.reset();

    return CDialogEx::DestroyWindow();
}
```

### `CWebBrowser` Header

```
#pragma once

#include <EventToken.h>
#include <functional>
#include <map>

struct ICoreWebView2Environment;
struct ICoreWebView2Controller;

struct CWebBrowserImpl;
class CView;

class CWebBrowser : public CWnd
{
public:
   enum class CallbackType 
   {
      CreationCompleted,
      NavigationCompleted,
      TitleChanged,
   };

   using CallbackFunc = std::function<void()>;

public:
   CWebBrowser();
   virtual ~CWebBrowser();

   virtual BOOL Create(
      LPCTSTR lpszClassName,
      LPCTSTR lpszWindowName, 
      DWORD dwStyle,
      const RECT& rect,
      CWnd* pParentWnd, 
      UINT nID,
      CCreateContext* = NULL) override;

   BOOL CreateAsync(
      DWORD dwStyle,
      const RECT& rect,
      CWnd* pParentWnd,
      UINT nID,
      CallbackFunc onCreated);

   void RegisterCallback(CallbackType const type, CallbackFunc callback);

   RECT GetBounds();
   void SetBounds(LONG const width, LONG const height) { Resize(width, height); }
   void Resize(LONG const width, LONG const height);

   CString GetLocationURL();

   void Navigate(CString const & url, CallbackFunc onComplete);
   void NavigatePost(CString const& url, CString const& content, CString const& headers, CallbackFunc onComplete = nullptr);
   void GoBack();
   void GoForward();
   void Reload();
   void Stop();
   bool IsNavigating() const { return m_isNavigating; }
   void DisablePopups();

   void PrintDocument();
   CString GetTitle() const { return m_strTitle; }

   void SetParent(CWnd* pParent) { m_pParent = pParent; }
   bool IsWebViewCreated() const;

protected:
   DECLARE_DYNCREATE(CWebBrowser)
   DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()

private:
   CWebBrowserImpl* m_pImpl;
   std::map<CallbackType, CallbackFunc> m_callbacks;

   EventRegistrationToken m_navigationCompletedToken = {};
   EventRegistrationToken m_navigationStartingToken = {};
   EventRegistrationToken m_documentTitleChangedToken = {};

   bool m_isNavigating = false;
   CWnd* m_pParent = nullptr;
   CString m_strTitle;

private:
   void RunAsync(CallbackFunc callback);

   void CloseWebView();
   void RegisterEventHandlers();
   void ResizeToClientArea();
   void NavigateTo(CString url);
   CString NormalizeUrl(CString url);

   static CString GetInstallPath();
   static CString GetInstallPathFromRegistry(bool const searchWebView = true);
   static CString GetInstallPathFromDisk(bool const searchWebView = true);
   static CString GetUserDataFolder();

   void InitializeWebView();
   HRESULT OnCreateEnvironmentCompleted(HRESULT result, ICoreWebView2Environment* environment);
   HRESULT OnCreateWebViewControllerCompleted(HRESULT result, ICoreWebView2Controller* controller);

   static PCTSTR GetWindowClass();
   static LRESULT CALLBACK WndProcStatic(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
   bool HandleWindowMessage(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, LRESULT* result);

   BOOL CreateHostWindow(
      LPCTSTR lpszClassName,
      LPCTSTR lpszWindowName,
      DWORD dwStyle,
      const RECT& rect,
      CWnd* pParentWnd,
      UINT nID);
};
```

### `CWebBrowser` Source

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <wrl.h>
#include "wil/com.h"

using namespace Microsoft::WRL;

#include "EdgeWebBrowser.h"
#include "Messages.h"

#include "WebView2.h"

#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

#include <shlwapi.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"shlwapi.lib")
#include "shlobj.h"

#pragma comment(lib,"Version.lib")

#include <string>

#define CHECK_FAILURE_STRINGIFY(arg)         #arg
#define CHECK_FAILURE_FILE_LINE(file, line)  ([](HRESULT hr){ CheckFailure(hr, L"Failure at " CHECK_FAILURE_STRINGIFY(file) L"(" CHECK_FAILURE_STRINGIFY(line) L")"); })
#define CHECK_FAILURE                        CHECK_FAILURE_FILE_LINE(__FILE__, __LINE__)
#define CHECK_FAILURE_BOOL(value)            CHECK_FAILURE((value) ? S_OK : E_UNEXPECTED)

struct CWebBrowserImpl
{
   wil::com_ptr<ICoreWebView2Environment>    m_webViewEnvironment;
   wil::com_ptr<ICoreWebView2Environment2>   m_webViewEnvironment2;
   wil::com_ptr<ICoreWebView2>               m_webView;
   wil::com_ptr<ICoreWebView2_2>             m_webView2;
   wil::com_ptr<ICoreWebView2Controller>     m_webController;
   wil::com_ptr<ICoreWebView2Settings>       m_webSettings;
};

void ShowFailure(HRESULT hr, CString const & message)
{
   CString text;
   text.Format(L"%s (0x%08X)", (LPCTSTR)message, hr);

   ::MessageBox(nullptr, static_cast<LPCTSTR>(text), L"Failure", MB_OK);
}

void CheckFailure(HRESULT hr, CString const & message)
{
   if (FAILED(hr))
   {    
      CString text;
      text.Format(L"%s : 0x%08X", (LPCTSTR)message, hr);

      // TODO: log text
     
      std::exit(hr);
   }
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CWebBrowser

IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE(CWebBrowser, CWnd)

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CWebBrowser properties
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CWebBrowser, CWnd)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

CWebBrowser::CWebBrowser():m_pImpl(new CWebBrowserImpl())
{
   m_callbacks[CallbackType::CreationCompleted] = nullptr;
   m_callbacks[CallbackType::NavigationCompleted] = nullptr;
}

CWebBrowser::~CWebBrowser()
{
   SetWindowLongPtr(m_hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA, 0);
   CloseWebView();
   delete m_pImpl;
}

BOOL CWebBrowser::CreateHostWindow(
   LPCTSTR lpszClassName,
   LPCTSTR lpszWindowName,
   DWORD dwStyle,
   const RECT& rect,
   CWnd* pParentWnd,
   UINT nID)
{
   if (lpszClassName == nullptr)
      lpszClassName = GetWindowClass();

   if (!CWnd::Create(lpszClassName, lpszWindowName, dwStyle, rect, pParentWnd, nID))
      return FALSE;

   ::SetWindowLongPtr(m_hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG_PTR)this);

   return TRUE;
}

BOOL CWebBrowser::Create(
   LPCTSTR lpszClassName,
   LPCTSTR lpszWindowName,
   DWORD dwStyle,
   const RECT& rect,
   CWnd* pParentWnd, 
   UINT nID,
   CCreateContext*)
{
   if (!CreateHostWindow(lpszClassName, lpszWindowName, dwStyle, rect, pParentWnd, nID))
      return FALSE;

   InitializeWebView();

   return TRUE;
}

BOOL CWebBrowser::CreateAsync(
   DWORD dwStyle,
   const RECT& rect,
   CWnd* pParentWnd, 
   UINT nID,
   CallbackFunc onCreated)
{
   if (!CreateHostWindow(nullptr, nullptr, dwStyle, rect, pParentWnd, nID))
      return FALSE;

   m_callbacks[CallbackType::CreationCompleted] = onCreated;

   InitializeWebView();

   return TRUE;
}

void CWebBrowser::RegisterCallback(CallbackType const type, CallbackFunc callback)
{
   m_callbacks[type] = callback;
}

void CWebBrowser::CloseWebView()
{
   if (m_pImpl->m_webView)
   {
      m_pImpl->m_webView->remove_NavigationCompleted(m_navigationCompletedToken);
      m_pImpl->m_webView->remove_NavigationStarting(m_navigationStartingToken);
      m_pImpl->m_webView->remove_DocumentTitleChanged(m_documentTitleChangedToken);

      m_pImpl->m_webController->Close();

      m_pImpl->m_webController = nullptr;
      m_pImpl->m_webView = nullptr;
      m_pImpl->m_webView2 = nullptr;
      m_pImpl->m_webSettings = nullptr;
   }

   m_pImpl->m_webViewEnvironment2 = nullptr;
   m_pImpl->m_webViewEnvironment = nullptr;
}

void CWebBrowser::InitializeWebView()
{
   CloseWebView();

   CString subFolder = GetInstallPath();
   CString appData = GetUserDataFolder();
   ICoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions* options = nullptr;

   HRESULT hr = CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentWithOptions(
      subFolder, 
      appData,
      options,
      Callback<ICoreWebView2CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentCompletedHandler>(
         this, 
         &CWebBrowser::OnCreateEnvironmentCompleted).Get());

   if (!SUCCEEDED(hr))
   {
      CString text;
      if (hr == HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND))
      {
         text = L"Cannot found the WebView2 component.";
      }
      else
      {
         text = L"Cannot create the webview environment.";
      }

      ShowFailure(hr, text);
   }
}

HRESULT CWebBrowser::OnCreateEnvironmentCompleted(
   HRESULT result, 
   ICoreWebView2Environment* environment)
{
   CHECK_FAILURE(result);

   if (!environment)
      return E_FAIL;

   CHECK_FAILURE(environment->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&m_pImpl->m_webViewEnvironment)));
   CHECK_FAILURE(environment->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&m_pImpl->m_webViewEnvironment2)));

   CHECK_FAILURE(m_pImpl->m_webViewEnvironment->CreateCoreWebView2Controller(
      m_hWnd, 
      Callback<ICoreWebView2CreateCoreWebView2ControllerCompletedHandler>(
         this, 
         &CWebBrowser::OnCreateWebViewControllerCompleted).Get()));

   return S_OK;
}

HRESULT CWebBrowser::OnCreateWebViewControllerCompleted(
   HRESULT result, 
   ICoreWebView2Controller* controller)
{
   if (result == S_OK)
   {
      if (controller != nullptr)
      {
         m_pImpl->m_webController = controller;
         CHECK_FAILURE(controller->get_CoreWebView2(&m_pImpl->m_webView));

         if (!m_pImpl->m_webView)
            return E_FAIL;

         CHECK_FAILURE(m_pImpl->m_webView->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&m_pImpl->m_webView2)));

         CHECK_FAILURE(m_pImpl->m_webView->get_Settings(&m_pImpl->m_webSettings));

         RegisterEventHandlers();

         ResizeToClientArea();
      }

      auto callback = m_callbacks[CallbackType::CreationCompleted];
      if (callback != nullptr)
         RunAsync(callback);
   }
   else
   {
      ShowFailure(result, L"Cannot create webview environment.");
   }

   return S_OK;
}

void CWebBrowser::RegisterEventHandlers()
{
   // NavigationCompleted handler
   CHECK_FAILURE(m_pImpl->m_webView->add_NavigationCompleted(
      Callback<ICoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventHandler>(
         [this](
            ICoreWebView2*, 
            ICoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventArgs* args) -> HRESULT
         {
            m_isNavigating = false;

            BOOL success;
            CHECK_FAILURE(args->get_IsSuccess(&success));

            if (!success)
            {
               COREWEBVIEW2_WEB_ERROR_STATUS webErrorStatus{};
               CHECK_FAILURE(args->get_WebErrorStatus(&webErrorStatus));
               if (webErrorStatus == COREWEBVIEW2_WEB_ERROR_STATUS_DISCONNECTED)
               {
                  // Do something here if you want to handle a specific error case.
                  // In most cases this isn't necessary, because the WebView will
                  // display its own error page automatically.
               }
            }

            wil::unique_cotaskmem_string uri;
            m_pImpl->m_webView->get_Source(&uri);

            if (wcscmp(uri.get(), L"about:blank") == 0)
            {
               uri = wil::make_cotaskmem_string(L"");
            }

            auto callback = m_callbacks[CallbackType::NavigationCompleted];
            if (callback != nullptr)
               RunAsync(callback);

            return S_OK;
         })
      .Get(),
            &m_navigationCompletedToken));

   // NavigationStarting handler
   CHECK_FAILURE(m_pImpl->m_webView->add_NavigationStarting(
      Callback<ICoreWebView2NavigationStartingEventHandler>(
         [this](
            ICoreWebView2*,
            ICoreWebView2NavigationStartingEventArgs* args) -> HRESULT
         {
            wil::unique_cotaskmem_string uri;
            CHECK_FAILURE(args->get_Uri(&uri));

            m_isNavigating = true;
            
            return S_OK;
         }).Get(), &m_navigationStartingToken));

   // DocumentTitleChanged handler
   CHECK_FAILURE(m_pImpl->m_webView->add_DocumentTitleChanged(
      Callback<ICoreWebView2DocumentTitleChangedEventHandler>(
         [this](ICoreWebView2* sender, IUnknown* args) -> HRESULT {
            wil::unique_cotaskmem_string title;
            CHECK_FAILURE(sender->get_DocumentTitle(&title));

            m_strTitle = title.get();
            
            auto callback = m_callbacks[CallbackType::TitleChanged];
            if (callback != nullptr)
               RunAsync(callback);

            return S_OK;
         })
      .Get(), &m_documentTitleChangedToken));
}

void CWebBrowser::ResizeToClientArea()
{
   if (m_pImpl->m_webController)
   {
      RECT bounds;
      GetClientRect(&bounds);
      m_pImpl->m_webController->put_Bounds(bounds);
   }
}

RECT CWebBrowser::GetBounds()
{
   RECT rc{0,0,0,0};
   if (m_pImpl->m_webController)
   {
      m_pImpl->m_webController->get_Bounds(&rc);
   }

   return rc;
}

void CWebBrowser::Resize(LONG const width, LONG const height)
{
   SetWindowPos(nullptr, 0, 0, width, height, SWP_NOMOVE| SWP_NOREPOSITION);
}

CString CWebBrowser::GetLocationURL()
{
   CString url;
   if (m_pImpl->m_webView)
   {
      wil::unique_cotaskmem_string uri;
      m_pImpl->m_webView->get_Source(&uri);

      if (wcscmp(uri.get(), L"about:blank") == 0)
      {
         uri = wil::make_cotaskmem_string(L"");
      }

      url = uri.get();
   }

   return url;
}

CString CWebBrowser::NormalizeUrl(CString url)
{
   if (url.Find(_T("://")) < 0)
   {
      if (url.GetLength() > 1 && url[1] == ':')
         url = _T("file://") + url;
      else
         url = _T("http://") + url;
   }

   return url;
}

void CWebBrowser::NavigateTo(CString url)
{
   m_pImpl->m_webView->Navigate(NormalizeUrl(url));
}

void CWebBrowser::Navigate(CString const & url, CallbackFunc onComplete)
{
   if (m_pImpl->m_webView)
   {      
      m_callbacks[CallbackType::NavigationCompleted] = onComplete;
      NavigateTo(url);
   }
}

// The raw request header string delimited by CRLF(optional in last header).
void CWebBrowser::NavigatePost(CString const& url, CString const& content, CString const& headers, std::function<void()> onComplete)
{
   if (!m_pImpl->m_webView) return;

   CString normalizedUrl{ NormalizeUrl(url) };

   m_callbacks[CallbackType::NavigationCompleted] = onComplete;

   wil::com_ptr<ICoreWebView2WebResourceRequest> webResourceRequest;
   wil::com_ptr<IStream> postDataStream = SHCreateMemStream(
      reinterpret_cast<const BYTE*>(static_cast<LPCTSTR>(content)),
      content.GetLength() + 1);

   CHECK_FAILURE(m_pImpl->m_webViewEnvironment2->CreateWebResourceRequest(
      CT2W(normalizedUrl),
      L"POST",
      postDataStream.get(),
      CT2W(headers),
      &webResourceRequest));

   CHECK_FAILURE(m_pImpl->m_webView2->NavigateWithWebResourceRequest(webResourceRequest.get()));
}
void CWebBrowser::PrintDocument()
{
   if (m_pImpl->m_webView)
   {
      m_pImpl->m_webView->ExecuteScript(L"window.print();", nullptr);
   }
}

void CWebBrowser::Stop()
{
   if (m_pImpl->m_webView)
   {
      m_pImpl->m_webView->Stop();
   }
}

void CWebBrowser::Reload()
{
   if (m_pImpl->m_webView)
   {
      m_pImpl->m_webView->Reload();
   }
}

void CWebBrowser::GoBack()
{
   if (m_pImpl->m_webView)
   {
      BOOL possible = FALSE;
      m_pImpl->m_webView->get_CanGoBack(&possible);
      if(possible)
         m_pImpl->m_webView->GoBack();
   }
}

void CWebBrowser::GoForward()
{
   if (m_pImpl->m_webView)
   {
      BOOL possible = FALSE;
      m_pImpl->m_webView->get_CanGoForward(&possible);
      if (possible)
         m_pImpl->m_webView->GoForward();
   }
}

void CWebBrowser::DisablePopups()
{
   if (m_pImpl->m_webSettings)
   {
      m_pImpl->m_webSettings->put_AreDefaultScriptDialogsEnabled(FALSE);
   }
}

PCTSTR CWebBrowser::GetWindowClass()
{
   static PCTSTR windowClass = []
   {
      static TCHAR const * className = L"EdgeBrowserHost";

      WNDCLASSEX wcex;
      wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

      wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
      wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProcStatic;
      wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
      wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
      wcex.hInstance = AfxGetInstanceHandle();
      wcex.hIcon = nullptr;
      wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
      wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
      wcex.lpszMenuName = nullptr;
      wcex.lpszClassName = className;
      wcex.hIconSm = nullptr;

      ATOM result = RegisterClassEx(&wcex);
      if (result == 0)
      {
         [[maybe_unused]] DWORD lastError = ::GetLastError();
      }

      return className;
   }();

   return windowClass;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK CWebBrowser::WndProcStatic(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
   if (auto app = (CWebBrowser*)::GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA))
   {
      LRESULT result = 0;
      if (app->HandleWindowMessage(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam, &result))
      {
         return result;
      }
   }

   return ::DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}

bool CWebBrowser::HandleWindowMessage(
   HWND, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, LRESULT* result)
{
   *result = 0;
   
   switch (message)
   {
   case WM_SIZE:
   {
      if (lParam != 0)
      {
         ResizeToClientArea();
         return true;
      }
   }
   break;
   case MSG_RUN_ASYNC_CALLBACK:
   {
      auto* task = reinterpret_cast<CallbackFunc*>(wParam);
      (*task)();
      delete task;
      return true;
   }
   break;
   }

   return false;
}

void CWebBrowser::RunAsync(CallbackFunc callback)
{
   auto* task = new CallbackFunc(callback);
   PostMessage(MSG_RUN_ASYNC_CALLBACK, reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(task), 0);
}

bool CWebBrowser::IsWebViewCreated() const
{
   return m_pImpl->m_webView != nullptr;
}

CString CWebBrowser::GetInstallPath()
{
   static CString path = []
   {  
      auto installPath = GetInstallPathFromRegistry();   // check registry for WebView2
      if (installPath.IsEmpty())
         installPath = GetInstallPathFromDisk();         // check disk for WebView2
      if (installPath.IsEmpty())
         installPath = GetInstallPathFromRegistry(false);// check registry for Edge
      if (installPath.IsEmpty())
         installPath = GetInstallPathFromDisk(false);    // check disk for Edge

      return installPath;
   }(); 

   return path;
}

CString CWebBrowser::GetInstallPathFromRegistry(bool const searchWebView)
{
   CString path;

   HKEY handle = nullptr;

   LSTATUS result = ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND;

   if (searchWebView)
   {
      result = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
         LR"(SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Microsoft EdgeWebView)",
         0,
         KEY_READ,
         &handle);

      if (result != ERROR_SUCCESS)
         result = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
            LR"(SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Microsoft EdgeWebView)",
            0,
            KEY_READ,
            &handle);
   }
   else
   {
      result = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
         LR"(SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Microsoft Edge)",
         0,
         KEY_READ,
         &handle);

      if (result != ERROR_SUCCESS)
         result = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
            LR"(SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Microsoft Edge)",
            0,
            KEY_READ,
            &handle);
   }

   if (result == ERROR_SUCCESS)
   {
      TCHAR buffer[MAX_PATH + 1]{ 0 };
      DWORD type = REG_SZ;
      DWORD size = MAX_PATH;
      result = RegQueryValueEx(handle, L"InstallLocation", 0, &type, reinterpret_cast<LPBYTE>(buffer), &size);
      if (result == ERROR_SUCCESS) 
         path += CString{ buffer };

      TCHAR version[100]{ 0 };
      size = 100;
      result = RegQueryValueEx(handle, L"Version", 0, &type, reinterpret_cast<LPBYTE>(version), &size);
      if (result == ERROR_SUCCESS)
      {
         if (path.GetAt(path.GetLength() - 1) != L'\\')
            path += L"\\";
         path += CString{ version };
      }
      else
         path.Empty();

      RegCloseKey(handle);
   }

   return path;
}

CString CWebBrowser::GetInstallPathFromDisk(bool const searchWebView)
{
   CString path =
      searchWebView ?
      LR"(c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\EdgeWebView\Application\)" :
      LR"(c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\)";
   CString pattern = path + L"*";

   WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd{ 0 };
   HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFile(pattern, &ffd);
   if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
   {
      [[maybe_unused]] DWORD error = ::GetLastError();
      return {};
   }

   do
   {
      if (ffd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
      {
         CString name{ ffd.cFileName };
         int a, b, c, d;
         if (4 == swscanf_s(ffd.cFileName, L"%d.%d.%d.%d", &a, &b, &c, &d))
         {
            FindClose(hFind);
            return path + name;
         }
      }
   } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &ffd) != 0);

   FindClose(hFind);

   return {};
}

CString CWebBrowser::GetUserDataFolder()
{
   TCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH]{ 0 };
   ::SHGetFolderPath(nullptr, CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA, nullptr, 0, szPath);
   ::PathAppend(szPath, LR"(\Demos\)");
   ::PathAppend(szPath, L"MfcEdgeDemo");
   return CString{ szPath };
}
```

It works. One final comment, atleast for current ooperating systems... Make sure you have installed the [WebView2 Runtime](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/).

Comment: One problem I have noticed though is that I can't see any scroll bars.